# Find successive increasing numbers within a list

Tags: algorithm, list, recursion

Working on a larger problem, and part of it requires finding successive numbers within a given list, using recursion

```
[1,2,3,8,6,7]
```

output required

`[[1,2,3],8,[6,7]]`

I have dealt with 
empty list case
List with only one value case,
but I am stuck how to do the above case via recursion.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far. Tagging your question with the appropriate language would help too.

Comment: `output required

[[1,2,3],8,[6,7]]` how is it *not* `[[1, 2, 3, 8], [6, 7]]`? (`successive` has more than one interpretation, one being *next input datum*)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to do this recursively? It might be easier just to do it linearly.

Something like this maybe?

```
Function increasing(originalArray) {
     Let groupedArray = [ ]
     Let subArray = [ ]
     For(let i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++){
         If(subArray.length === 0){
             subArray = subArray.concat(originalArray[i])
          } else if(originalArray[i] - subArray[subArray.length - 1] === 1){
              subArray = subArray.concat(originalArray[i])
          } else {
             groupedArray = groupedArray.concat(subArray)
             subArray = [originalArray[i]]
          }
      }
     Return groupedArray
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to develop my recursion skills

Comment: Oh I see, in that case maybe you could have a function that finds the first increasing series and then returns that series concatenated with that same function called with the rest of the list?

Answer (score 0):

A common algorithmic technique is called [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm). I like to think of it as asking these questions:

1. If the scope of this problem were very small, could it easily be solved?
2. If I had multiple solutions to subsets of this problem could I combine them easily to solve the larger problem?

Now let's apply it to your problem. Instead of lone numbers and arrays like you have I am going to call them arrays of length 1 for simplicity sake. If you had to do this with an array of size 1 it would be easy. The answer would always just be the same array you put in inside another array. If you had two arrays that this had already been done to you could combine them. If the last value of the first array is one smaller than the first value of the second then combine the last sub array of the first half and the first sub array of the last half into an array of continuous numbers, otherwise just merge the two solved arrays normally.

Here is the solution implemented in python, sorry not the neatest but it gets the job done:

```
def myFunc(arr):
  # If there is only 1 element wrap in an array
  if (len(arr) == 1):
    return [arr]
  else:
    # apply the func to first and second array halves
    arrOne = myFunc(arr[:len(arr) / 2])
    arrTwo = myFunc(arr[len(arr) / 2:])

    # last array of the first
    arrOneEnd = arrOne[len(arrOne) - 1]
    # first array of the last
    arrTwoStart = arrTwo[0]

    # if the last element of the last array is 
    # 1 less than the first element of the first array
    if (arrOneEnd[len(arrOneEnd) - 1] - arrTwoStart[0] == -1):
      # Append them combining the first and last
      return arrOne[:len(arrOne) - 1] + [arrOneEnd + arrTwoStart] + arrTwo[1:]
    else:
      # Otherwise just append
      return arrOne + arrTwo
```

Then you can map all of the arrays of length 1 to their lone element:

```
def myFinalFunc(arr):
  return map(lambda subArr: if(len(subArr) == 1) subArr[0] else subArr, arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what data structure you mean here: `[[1,2,3],8,[6,7]]` so packed all output results (including single-item ones) in sublists

```
def SuccRec(lst, start, idx):
    if (idx >= len(lst)):
        print(lst[start:idx])
    else:
        if (lst[idx] != lst[idx-1] + 1):
             print(lst[start:idx])
             SuccRec(lst, idx, idx + 1)
        else:
             SuccRec(lst, start, idx + 1)


SuccRec([1,2,3,8,6,7], 0, 1)

output:
[1, 2, 3]
[8]
[6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's generalize a bit.

Keep on adding `item` into current `chunk` if the `chunk` is *empty* or the `condition` met between `last` item in the `chunk` and `item`. Otherwise start up a *new* `chunk`. In your case the condition is

```
 item - last == 1
```

As we can see, we have a direct (not *recoursive*) algorithm. C# implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> Successive<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                             Func<T, T, bool> condition) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  else if (null == condition)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("condition");

  List<T> chunk = new List<T>();

  foreach (var item in source) {
    if (!chunk.Any() || condition(chunk.Last(), item))
      chunk.Add(item);              // keep on adding into current chunk
    else {
      yield return chunk.ToArray(); // return current chunk

      chunk.Clear();                // start a new one
      chunk.Add(item);
    }
  }

  if (chunk.Any())
    yield return chunk.ToArray();
}
```

Test:

```
  int[] data = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 7 };

  // In our case the condition (successive items) is "current - last == 1"
  var result = Successive(data, (last, current) => current - last == 1)
    .Select(chunk => chunk.Length == 1     // ? : - to provide required output format
       ? chunk[0].ToString()
       : $"[{string.Join(",", chunk)}]");

  string report = $"[{string.Join(",", result)}]";

  Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
 [[1,2,3],8,[6,7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion with lots of comments for readability:

```
myList = [1,2,3,8,6,7]
newList = []

def treatItem(i=0, startOfRange=myList[0]):
    """
        Treat each item of the list recursively
        @param i : index of an element in myList
        @param startOfRange: start of the range the element belongs to
    """
    if (i+1 == len(myList)):
        # Here: we treat the last value of the list (so this is the end of a last range)
        # Store this range in newList
        lastRange = list(range(startOfRange,myList[i]+1))
        newList.append(lastRange)
        return
    elif (myList[i] + 1 != myList[i+1]):
        # Here: this is the end of a range
        # Store this range in newList
        newRange = list(range(startOfRange,myList[i]+1))
        newList.append(newRange)
        # Treat the next item, starting a new range
        treatItem(i+1, startOfRange=myList[i+1])
    else:
        # Here: this is not the end of a range
        # Treat the next item, without starting a new range
        treatItem(i+1, startOfRange=startOfRange)

treatItem()

print(newList) # [[1, 2, 3], [8], [6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Haskel attempt :)

```hs
f [] = []
f [x] = [[x]]
f (x:xs)
  | z == succ x = (x:z:zs):zzs
  | otherwise   = [x]:rest
    where rest@((z:zs):zzs) = f xs

main = print(f [1,2,3,8,6,7])
```